# Minka Concept II Use With 3-Party Wall Dimmer

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I have an older Minka Concept II 44" ceiling fan along with a newer one. The older one is the type that uses a standard screw-in light which currently has an LED bulb. The only label with a model number is on the ceiling mount plate which has Sept 2003" YL" and Model: AC-526(F518)"BB". On the newer one, it works well when controlled by a Lutron MACL-LFQ Maestro light/fan controller but this older one does not. Can anyone advise how to wire it directly, bypassing the wireless components? The actual color coding does not match that shown in the manual and has white (common), black (for the light) and four very small wires in yellow, red, pink and grey going into the fan motor.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in both the old and the new fans please?

Comment: I’m afraid that this is not a generic electrical question but rather requires an answer from someone with intimate personal knowledge of Minka fans.